# Laravel 8 and SQL Server: problem with timestamp

Tags: laravel

Hello everyone and happy new year,

I'm converting my project to use SQL Server instead of MySQL and I'm struggling with the problem of managing timestamps.

In the project, I have this code:

```
Customers::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subDays('7'), Carbon::now()])->count();
```

which gives me back the number of new customers registered in the last 7 days.
Using MySQL no problem whatsoever while with SQL Server I get this error:

> Converting an nvarchar data type to datetime resulted in a value
> outside of the allowable range.

despite in my model, I have set

```
public function getDateFormat()
{
    return 'Y-m-d H: i: s.v';
}
```

to get the values in milliseconds.

What did I forget to set up?

Comment: Can you provide details about an example field in your MySQL database and its counterpart in SQL Server? What is their type?

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that a conversion failed. Possible reasons:

## The date does not exist

If you get February 30th as the input, it will fail.

## Input not complying to the format in use

To detect whether this is the problem, you will need to find out what the generated SQL is and find out which value caused this problem. After carefully studying the conversion you should be able to determine what the problem and solution is.